# How to create a SQL function which splits comma separated value?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a function in SQL Server which takes a comma separated string a parameter, splits it and returns one value at a time. The basic idea here is to call that function from a query. Something like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_VALUE(@IN_CSV)
RETURN VARCHAR AS
 -- LOGIC TO RETURN A SINGLE VALUE FROM CSV
END
```

I want to call this function from a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEMO_PROC @IN_CSV VARCHAR(5000), @OUT VARCHAR(5000) OUTPUT AS
   BEGIN
     SELECT @OUT= CONCAT(A.VALUE1,B.VALUE2) FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID=B.ID WHERE A.ID 
     IN(--CALL THE FUNCTION AND GET ONE VALUE);
   END;
```

I have to create a loop or cursor to point to a particular value every time. Is this practically possible to? If yes then how can I do that?

Comment: *"splits it and returns one value at a time"* that isn't how a function works. A scalar function can't return multiple scalar results and a table-value function can only return one dataset, not many.

Comment: Perhaps is you supply a small data sample and desired results, there may be a better solution... I'm leaning towards CROSS APPLY , but that is just a guess.

Comment: @John Cappelletti Basically what I want to do is split the csv inside the IN and use each value at a time to get its other values from table. The sample input is like ('abc1,def2,.,.') and as a output we get VALUE1 and VALUE2 of ID abc1 , def2,.. etc respectively

Comment: @LArnu Is there some other design which can help in this? Split string and select one of them at a time. Is there any regular expression or any other solution to be written inside IN clause in above query?

Comment: The only way you could get a separate dataset for each value would be with a `CURSOR` or `WHILE`, which will be inherently slow, and you would have to handle everything inside an SP. Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. You need to tell us the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: @Larnu Due to some design requests I have to pass a comma separated string as input parameter to the SP, split it inside the SP and use it in the query. This is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mention, you'll have to use a `CURSOR` to do this, however, the fact you want to do it this way infers a (large) design flaw:

```
DECLARE @value varchar(8000)

DECLARE Delimited_Values CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT [value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT('a,b,c,d,e',',')

OPEN Delimited_Values;

FETCH NEXT FROM Delimited_Values
INTO @value;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @value; --Do your stuff here

    FETCH NEXT FROM Delimited_Values
    INTO @value;

END;

CLOSE Delimited_Values;
DEALLOCATE Delimited_Values;
```