# How to get the result of string_split() in a row?

Tags: sql-server, split

I want to split comma separated values using `string_split(@var,',')`  I want any single row of the result into a variable . How do we do that in SQL server?

Comment: *"I want the result of this function into a single row"* That doesn't make sense. `STRING_SPLIT` separates a delimited scalar value into rows. If you want your value in a single row, you already have it; as it is.

Comment: Without making any assumptions, you logically cannot. A resultset, like a table, has a fixed schema (meaning datatype and number of columns). Your <string to split> can represent any number of columns.

Comment: @Larnu I have edited the question. I actually want to select one row at a time from the result.

Comment: This sounds like you and radhika bahirat are working on the [same assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62536647/2029983).

Comment: @Larnu - looking at your answer, I think it is barely a pass ;) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
       
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

EXAMPLE

```
DECLARE @StringArray VARCHAR(max)
        Set  @StringArray= 'a,b,c,d,f';
select * from dbo.fnSplitString(@StringArray,',')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
-- =============================================
-- fn_split50
-- split string by delimiter and return values in columns (value1, value2,...,value50)
--      if count of value > [@columnCnt] or [50] wraps other value to the next line:
--          so it allows to get "array data"
--          nn will indicare rowNo (from 1)
--      faster then dbo.fn_GetToken(), because process whole string at once
-- =============================================
/*
    select * from dbo.fn_split50('zz1,aa2,ss3,dd4,ff5', ',', DEFAULT)
    
    select * from dbo.fn_split50('zz1,aa2,ss3,dd4,ff5,gg6,hh7,jj8,ww9,qq10', ',', 3)

    select * from dbo.fn_split50('zz1,aa2,ss3,dd4,ff5,gg6,hh7,jj8,ww9,qq10,zz1,aa2,ss3,dd4,ff5,gg6,hh7,jj8,ww9,qq10,zz1,aa2,ss3,dd4,ff5,gg6,hh7,jj8,ww9,qq10', ',', 3)

    select * from dbo.fn_split50('zz1,11,aa2,22,ss3,33,dd4,44,ff5,55,gg6,66,hh7,77,jj8,88,ww9,99,qq10,1010', ',',2)
*/

alter FUNCTION fn_Split50
(   
    @str varchar(max),
    @delim char(1), 
    @columnCnt int = 50
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT 
            nn = (nn - 1) / @columnCnt + 1, 
            nnn = 'value' + cast(((nn - 1) % @columnCnt) + 1 as varchar(10)), 
            value
        FROM (SELECT 
            nn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)),
            value
            FROM string_split(@str, @delim) aa
            ) aa
        where nn > 0
    ) bb
    PIVOT  
    (  
    max(value) 
    FOR nnn IN (    
        value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10,
        value11, value12, value13, value14, value15, value16, value17, value18, value19, value20,
        value21, value22, value23, value24, value25, value26, value27, value28, value29, value30,
        value31, value32, value33, value34, value35, value36, value37, value38, value39, value40,
        value41, value42, value43, value44, value45, value46, value47, value48, value49, value50        
     )  
    ) AS PivotTable 
)
```